# What is a word that could imply both "surplus" or "deficit"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a generic word that could mean either surplus or deficit. It would be used in a sentence such as:

"The tank had a surplus or deficit in fuel."

But "surplus or deficit" is replaced with a single word.

Comment: Consider *discrepancy*.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: I up-ticked both previous comments, but it would help if you offered a few more sample sentences in which you would use the word you are looking for (and tell us *why*). Are you trying to say a container doesn't have the "right amount" of something? Too much or too little? Just right? More context and an explanation would help.

Comment: ' An * irregularity*  in fuel stock'

Comment: The tank fuel supply is *out of bounds*.

Comment: If talking about money it would be "cash flow".

Comment: A fuel tank cannot be full and empty unless it's Schrodinger's cat. It has to be either full or empty, and those are states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accountants talk about *a profit and loss account*, *gains and losses on exchange*, *income and deficit*, so there is really nothing there that might help.

But in *standard costing* systems, one analyses ***variances*** from standard, which are either *favourable* or *adverse*.

So if these surpluses and deficits of which you speak are as measured against some sort of standard or expectation, you could certainly use the word ***variance***. The Greek letter *delta* is sometimes used as a symbol for variance.

Answer (score 4):

Use **disparity** for an unexpected difference.

Answer (score 1):

A ***delta***?

The words **surplus** and **deficit** both describe changes to an amount or value. In math, a change to a value is called a delta. In investing they use the term **value change**, so I assume they have no better single word for the concept.

If you don't mind getting creative with language you could use the non-word *preciation*, the base of the words appreciation and depreciation, though these are more specific to monetary value.

Answer (score -1):

In possible absence of an actual word, a new appropriate term could be coined as per the requirement.

I would suggest '**unfficient**', made from anglicisation of *un*- + *facere* to make/do; designed on lines of sufficient: being evolved from Latin *sufficere* to provide, be adequate, from *sub*- + *facere* to make/do.

Answer (score -1):

"The tank had reached a point of disequilibrium"

Answer (score -1):

A state of something: full or empty, with or without variables, etc.

The state of the tank was unknown. Whether it was full or empty.

Comment: Tsk tsk, really.